# How to use AsyncTask to load images from drawable into listView

Tags: android

I have a simple ListView which has image on the left and text in the right. Currently i am using a LazyAdapter to load images from drawable resource according to name of dishes.

I have created a array of image ID's and would be using that to setImageView.

The problem is, the scrolling is not smooth which i know due to the fact that all the image loading is done by the main thread. I googled a lot about AsyncTask, which allows us run background thread. I am not getting how to use AsyncTask to achieve by task as all the examples that i have seen on AsyncTask has image downloaded from URL.

Please help me in using AsyncTask to load list of images from drawable to Bitmap.

Here is my mail class:

ARRAY.image is an integer Array which has image ID's which is used in adapter to set ImageView

```
package love.cookbook.FirstPage;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.*;

public class ListViewSampleActivity extends SherlockListActivity {

    LazyAdapter adapter;

    public String packageName;
    public int imageID;
    String ingredientsImageName;

    public MySqliteHelper dbHelper;
    Cursor cur;


    String eachIngredientsImageName [];

    String listItemName;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.list_main);
    dbHelper = new MySqliteHelper(this);

    ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    final FirstPageActivity firstPage = new FirstPageActivity();


        ARRAY.dishes = intent.getStringArrayExtra("DISHES");
        ARRAY.description = intent.getStringArrayExtra("DESCRIPTION");
        ARRAY.timeToPrepare = intent.getStringArrayExtra("TIMETOPREPARE");
        ARRAY.lock = intent.getStringArrayExtra("LOCKVALUE");
        ARRAY.imageName = intent.getStringArrayExtra("IMAGENAME");

        ARRAY.nonVeg = intent.getStringArrayExtra("NONVEG");
        ARRAY.isFavourite = intent.getStringArrayExtra("ISFAVOURITE");

        /*
         * This code snippet is used to fetch the image id from the resource folder from the name fetched from database.
         */
        ARRAY.image = new int[ARRAY.imageName.length];

        packageName=this.getPackageName();
        for(int i=0;i<ARRAY.imageName.length;i++){
            ARRAY.image[i]=getResources().getIdentifier(ARRAY.imageName[i].toLowerCase(), "drawable", packageName);

        }


        adapter=new LazyAdapter (this, ARRAY.dishes,ARRAY.description,ARRAY.timeToPrepare,ARRAY.image,ARRAY.lock,ARRAY.nonVeg);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){


            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {

            }

        });
    }

}
```

Here is my Adapter class:

```
package love.cookbook.FirstPage;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

    public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Activity activity;
        private String[] dishes;
        private String[] recipeDescripion;
        private String[] timeToPrepare;
        private String[] lock;
        private String[] nonVeg;
        private int [] images;
        ViewHolder holder;
        Bitmap bitmap;
        private static LayoutInflater inflater=null; 

        public LazyAdapter(Activity a, String[] dishes, String[] recipeDescription,String[] timeToPrepare,int[] images,String [] lock,String [] nonVeg) {
            activity = a;
            this.dishes=dishes;
            this.images=images;
            this.bitmap = bitmap;
            this.recipeDescripion=recipeDescription;
            this.timeToPrepare=timeToPrepare;
            this.lock=lock;
            this.nonVeg=nonVeg;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            //View vi=convertView;
            if(convertView==null){
                //vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item,parent, false);
                //image = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
                holder.vegNonveggImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

                holder.textView1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                holder.textView2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                holder.textView3 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                convertView.setTag(holder);

            }
            else
                holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();


            holder.textView1.setText(dishes[position]);

            holder.image.setImageResource(images[position]);

            holder.textView2.setText(recipeDescripion[position]);
            holder.textView3.setText(timeToPrepare[position]); 

            if(nonVeg[position].equals("1")){
                holder.vegNonveggImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.non_veg_symbol);
            }
            else{
                holder.vegNonveggImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.veg_symbol);
            }


            return convertView;
        }

        public int getCount() {

            return dishes.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public class ViewHolder{
            ImageView image;
            TextView textView1;
            TextView textView2;
            TextView textView3;
            ImageView vegNonveggImageView;
        }


}
```

Comment: You can use [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) for asynchronous image displaying.

Answer (score 0):

Your non-smooth scrolling problem could be caused by the images taking up too much memory.

You can check this in Eclipse by going on the DDMS perspective and viewing the allocated memory size to see if it seems too large.

This can be checked by:

- Open the DDMS Perspective: Window > Open Perspective > DDMS,
- Locate the Devices View: Window > Show View > Devices
- Select your app in the list (the emulator must be running)
- Click update heap (looks like a half full green container)
- Locate the Heap View: Window > Show View > Heap
- Click Cause GC

If the total Size of the type `1-byte array(byte[], boolean[])` is too large this will likely cause scrolling issues.

I don't think an `AsyncTask` is going to solve your problems as updating Views has to be done on the UI (Main) thread anyway.

If the images your loading are too large you can minimize them using:

```
Bitmap smallIcon = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bigIcon, width, height, false);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the info. My 1-byte array has total size of 14.56MB with 532 as count. Could you please elaborate what these statistics mean? and do i need to create a Bitmap array to reduce the size of all images before sending it to LazyAdapter?

Comment: @user2757578 Yeh that seems a lot! the 532 doesn't mean too much but the 14.56MB means that you most likely have a lot of memory allocated in large Bitmaps (they are saved to memory as byte[]). Android applications typically are allowed to allocate about 16MB so almost all of your memory is taken up by images. Did you try and reduce their size using the createScaledBitmap method above? Also how big (pixels) are the images that your using? You could try and reduce their size manually if they are in your resources folder.